# Opposite of boost::python::extract<obj>

Tags: c++, python, boost, numpy, boost-python

I am working with the boost Python and NumPy API. I know on the C++ side of things, in the boost python namespace, we have the following ability to extract elements from numpy.ndarray by using a command like

```
float value = bp::extract<float>(someArray[someIndex]);
```

Now my question is, does there exist some command that does the opposite?

e.g.

```
someArray[someIndex] = bp::put<float>(value);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/python/doc/v2/to_python_converter.html only. and your example should be

```
float value = bp::extract<float>(someArray[someindex]);
```

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the correction of the above example, however, that is the way I typed it in. 

I must have to use some symbol to denote that it is example code, the web page seems to remove some of the code.

Comment: I see, I am new to this stack overflow business. I had to denote the block of text was code!

Answer (score 1):

Use `bp::object(value)` to convert `value` to Python using usual to-python conversion machinery.